# Getting this error when starting next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css

After installing the next.js project and starting it, it is giving me this error.

> error -
> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

But when I install Tailwind CSS in it, the app runs well. I don't know why it is not running without Tailwind.

Comment: Can you add your config files to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I cloned a legacy NextJS project today without Tailwind and the same error occurred (without any dependency changes). None of my newer projects (Next v10+) show this error, but I also use Tailwind on these. Removing a global scss file from `_app.js` also removes the error, but also global styling.

Adding Tailwind fixed it for me too, so something is including it as a dependency, or [a legacy json file is being cached](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/32443#issuecomment-1007972853).

So I have narrowed it down to either a cached global dependency, or a rogue json file.

Comment: Maybe this is the error is of legacy JSON because there is no such dependency that is causing this error. How can I remove legacy JSON or a Rogue JSON file which is being cached?